# My ubuntu 14.04 randomly starts typing this character '\' repeatedly

Tags: 14.04

It happens every time i try to type something or open a new tab in my browser. Here's the screenshot below:
[Every time i start typing something this backslash character appears randomly in between and many times it repeatedly keeps on typing itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C204t.png)

Is this some kind of a bug or a hardware problem related to my keyboard?I am new to ubuntu.Please help me resolve this problem

Comment: Check another keyboard it appears to be failing!

Comment: If it's a hardware issue, it could just be a sticky key. Try firmly tapping the \ key *hard*, from about one inch above it, using one finger. Repeat 5 times or so.

Answer (score 1):

It's about 99% that this is not a Ubuntu issue.  Try a different keyboard.

I usually just turn the keyboard upside down and pound it a few times to dislodge whatever "stuff" got jammed up in there.  Of course I have plenty of spare keyboards in case I break one doing this.

Could be that the membrane or switch, depending on what kind of keyboard it is, is having problems.

This doesn't seem to be applicable based on your particular symptoms but another place to look is system settings->keyboard.  In that tab, you can control the key repeat delay and speed.

If you have a fancy gaming keyboard, there could be a repeat sensitivity switch or other feature that needs to be reset.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think the problem is resolved. I tried cleaning the backspace key of my laptop which was causing a headache. The problem seems to have faded away.

Comment: Yay!  Glad you're back up running again.  Since my answer solved your problem....  :)